# Laravel faker email that pass the email validation email:rfc,dns

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I get

> invalid email address

when using faker to fill the email fields of my app.

`'email'  => ['required', 'email:rfc,dns']`

is there a way to make faker spit out valid email addresses that pass these tests?

I tried safeEmail and some others but they still fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem and it's all related to the `Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\DNSCheckValidation` class used by Laravel to validate an email (as you can see [here](https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator/blob/3.x/src/Validation/DNSCheckValidation.php#L24) `example` is a reserved top level domain).

There's no way of avoiding that an email created with `faker` passes this validation and, IMO, it's just as it should be. But we need to do our tests don't we?

There's a simple way (that can be used also in `FormRequest` or whatever you're using that implements the validator):

```php
// In your test:
$this->post('my-url', ['email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail])

// In your code
$emailRules = 'email:rfc';

if(!app()->runningUnitTests()) {
    $emailRules .= ',dns';
}

$validator = Validator::make($data, ['email' => ['required', $emailRules]]);
// [...]
```

Another way is to create a custom email validation rule that encapsulate the `runningUnitTests` logic (and I think it's much more cleaner)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\DNSCheckValidation;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\MultipleValidationWithAnd;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\NoRFCWarningsValidation;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\RFCValidation;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\SpoofCheckValidation;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\FilterEmailValidation;

/** @codeCoverageIgnore */
class ValidEmail implements Rule
{
    protected array $parameters;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $parameters = [])
    {
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (! is_string($value) && ! (is_object($value) && method_exists($value, '__toString'))) {
            return false;
        }

        $validations = collect($this->parameters)
            ->unique()
            ->map(function ($validation) {
                if ($validation === 'rfc') {
                    return new RFCValidation();
                } elseif ($validation === 'strict') {
                    return new NoRFCWarningsValidation();
                } elseif ($validation === 'dns' && !app()->runningUnitTests()) {
                    return new DNSCheckValidation();
                } elseif ($validation === 'spoof') {
                    return new SpoofCheckValidation();
                } elseif ($validation === 'filter') {
                    return new FilterEmailValidation();
                }

                return null;
            })
            ->values()
            ->filter()
            ->all() ?: [new RFCValidation()];

        return (new EmailValidator)->isValid($value, new MultipleValidationWithAnd($validations));
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return __('validation.email');
    }
}
```

Than in your code:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($data, ['email' => ['required', new ValidEmail()]]);

// OR

$validator = Validator::make($data, ['email' => ['required', new ValidEmail(['rfc','filter','dns'])]]);
// [...]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you create a free (as in, free sign-up email) address, it will pass the validation, even against `DNSCheckValidation`.

[You can create that using faker](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/internet/#freeemail). I tested this in Laravel 9 and now they pass validation.

```
// In your test file:
$email = $this->faker->unique()->freeEmail(); 
// 'marcelino.hyatt@yahoo.com', 'abby81@gmail.com'
$this->post('my-url', ['email' => $email])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting round this is to repeatedly create fake emails until you get one that passes validation, and use that.

```
use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\DNSCheckValidation;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\MultipleValidationWithAnd;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\RFCValidation;

// ...

// Create an email validator that mimics the validation used in the form request
$validator = new EmailValidator();
$multipleValidations = new MultipleValidationWithAnd([
    new RFCValidation(),
    new DNSCheckValidation()
]);

// Keep creating fake emails until we have a valid one
do {
    $email = $this->faker->email();
} while (!$validator->isValid($email, $multipleValidations));
```